# Using Session-variable to Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, razor

i have a website (products) where i call a function from my model. in this function i declare a session-variable:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["name"] = "x";
```

now in the site1-controller i try to work with this session-variable and try to redirect to site 2 if the session-variable is "x":

```
    public ActionResult Products() 
    { 

        if(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["name"]!=null)
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["name"].ToString() == "x")
            {
                return RedirectToAction( "Index", "Site2");
            }
            else {
            return View(); }

        }
        else
        {
        return View();
        }

    }
```

here is the controller of site2:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

but its not working. the products-site still loads, but with the layout of site2.

ive also tried to work with the session-variable on the products-site:

```
if (Session["role"] != null)
{
if (Session["role"].ToString() == "x")
{
    @Html.Action(actionName: "Index", controllerName: "Site2");
}
}
```

but still the same problem. can anyone point out to me what thats about and what i can do to solve this? thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to use the same session on the 2nd site?

Comment: @MarkCooper so i try to use the session-variable on my products.site, in my controller and in the function(called on products-site) but not on site2. but on the products-site, in the controller, and in the function the session-name should be the same

Comment: In the controller that is processing RedirectToAction("Index", "Site2") are you doing a redirect to site2? Your controller should do `return Redirect("http://site2");`

Comment: @MarkCooper ive edited my question and added the controller of site2.

Comment: I think that `RedirectToAction` is calling your controller on Site1. Try `return Redirect("http://site2")` instead of `return RedirectToAction( "Index", "Site2");`. Let me know how that goes.